# TextView does not stick to top right

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, padding

I'm having unnecessary padding in my textview object. Let's only focus at the top right textview in my picture below, the one with `1.48` and `6.91`. My requirement is the text draws to the top right corner of its own boundary so it is "top-justified" to the `DIJACOR` and "right-justified" to `+0.01`. I tried `gravity="top|right"`,  `includeFontPadding=false` and `paddings=0` but to no avail. For the second case, the render result shows some extra spaces after the `6.91`, making it not aligned to the `-0.01` below. Anyone can share with me on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image: grid view object]

Here's how I define the textView object:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceLast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Root ViewGroup:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >
```

Comment: +1 for this psychopath question ;-) ! Why don't you try to change text font?

Answer (score 3):

For case #2, the reason is that in most fonts, all the digits have the same character width in pixels. So the digit "1" and "8" take the same amount of width pixels. The reason is that you could write numbers on top of each other and the digits will always align. This means that a string like "4.1" will have more empty pixels on it's right than "4.8".
The solution is to use a font where each digit has a compact width, or to have your own view that renders the digits to a bitmap, finds the rightmost non-empty pixel, and shifts the bitmap to align it to the right.

Answer (score 2):

The padding which is visible to you is the default font padding, and and you are getting a little mismatch because of different font sizes.

You may try multiple things to fix this problem:

1) Try to fix the height of your TextViews (ie one with DIJACOR and 1.48), 
for ex: **android:layout_height="100dp"**, this shall solve your top alignment problem. You can adjust the height as per your need.

2) For extra space after "1". If you observe carefully that space is also there in 1.48, after "1". This means the font has extra space after "1". If our hypothesis is correct then using some different font shall fix this problem. Try using:
**android:fontFamily="sans-serif"**
OR
**android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"**
OR
**android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"**
OR
**android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"**

Answer (score 0):

I think the extra space of the 6.91 is inside the font, and you can not help it. To make it go all the way to the parent's top-right, make sure the parent has no padding.

Comment: There's an attribute called android:includeFontPadding that may affect that.

Comment: @Lesleh: [android:includeFontPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding) is only about ascenders and descenders, which are top and bottom padding.

Comment: @TomHart: There is a paddingTop in the parent which accounts for the top padding. I'm not entirely sure where the right padding comes from, but it looks like all views have the same, which indicates it's set in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of 1. 1 is thinner than 9 and all numbers contains in default area. But you can add `android:paddingRight="-1dp"`. Its not healthy but it should work.

Comment: I can't add the padding hack because other numbers rendered correctly

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to imitate your layout with standart fonts and I think that this padding pops up because of size difference between DIJACOR string and 1.78. Maybe you can try to add marginTop to DIJACOR string? If members of DIJACOR's column relate on DIJACOR, then adding marginTop won't change your layout significantly.

[image: From graphical layout view (equals to view in emulator)]

Answer (score 0):

I would say, remove the padding for `DIJACOR` TextView and `1.48` TextView and add margin Top to both. Or Add them to a Linear Layout where you can post `paddingTop` or `marginTop` as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the different font sizes. There are Characters that are higher than a 9, like the Î. These characters also need space above the usual numbers and letters. The space required is not a font spacing, so the XML directive will not help. Android uses the View height to align the views, that's why your conceived top borders don't match.

I faced the same problem and there is no easy way around it. The best you can do is using marginTop for the larger text with a negative margin but that can be buggy when it comes to animations. Alternatively you could also add a paddingTop to the other text view.